# SQL SERVER MAX Date in SUM of Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is possibly a simple question, but any help is much appreciated (I still have some lingering issues with SUM/GroupBy/MAX type implementations.

I have the below table:

```
+----------+-------+
|   Date   | Value |
+----------+-------+
| 1/1/2014 |     3 |
| 1/2/2014 |     9 |
| 1/3/2014 |     0 |
| 1/4/2014 |    11 |
|   ...    |   ... | 
| 7/9/2014 |     7 |
+----------+-------+
```

I want to input a `StartDate` and an `EndDate` and return a single row containing the `SUM(Value)` for the range as well as the `MAX(Date)` in that range...  That is to say, if I input:

```
BeginDate = '1/1/14'
EndDate   = '8/15/14'
```

I would like to return the sum of values as well as the date `'7/9/14'`
I know how to return the SUM(Value) where [Date Range] and I can find the Max[Date] in [Date Range], but putting it together escapes me, and I would like to do it efficiently. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two or more aggregations in the select list as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(Date), SUM(Value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-08-15';
```

Comment: Thanks! That was simpler than I imagined.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select Sum(Value), Max(Date)
from my_table
where Date Between @StartDate and @EndDate
```